# Restart compiled python script with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm programming a little app with python+tkinter that shows a window with some widgets. The window read data from remote sources and in some situations I want the application restart (close+open). It works fine when executing python script (source code), but is not working when compiled to an exe file (pyinstaller --onfile --windowed).

I've tried two ways, all two works perfectly in source code:

1. os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)
2. os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

When compiled to an exe, the application is closed but never restart. I've printed the values of argv to a log:

sys.argv[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Grid Positions\gridpositions.exe, sys.argv=['C:\Program Files (x86)\Grid Positions\gridpositions.exe']

The application is installed on C:\Program Files (x86)\Grid Positions, with correct writting permissions, using innosetup installer to make the setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

The calls to the `os.execv(...)` method are different depending on whether the application is running from within a python interpreter or an .exe from the pyinstaller.

Here is a function that takes care of this (tested on Windows, but not having the .exe to be unzipped within a temp folder):

```
import sys, os

def restart_main():
    # Restart the application...
    executable = sys.executable
    executable_filename = os.path.split(executable)[1]
    if executable_filename.lower().startswith('python'):
        # application is running within a python interpreter
        python = executable
        os.execv(python, [python, ] + sys.argv)
        pass
    else:
        # application is running as a standalone executable
        os.execv(executable, sys.argv)
        pass
    pass
```